# Mobile safari browser issue for z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

Currently on my site the only you can see this happen is safari on mobile I'm using jquery ui datepicker and after I clicked the datepicker if I scroll page to down datepicker is dissapearing and is not opening again

[Click to see live](https://www.anitur.com)

I have no idea why this only happens in and how to solve this issue for safari.

I share my js code but I'm sure this is not about with my js code because it's very basic and there is nothing will affect my datepicker

here you are

```js
function datePicker() {
    var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY",
        from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: 0,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            closeText: 'Temizle',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            },
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
                    $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find("#checkout,.checkout").focus();
                }, this), 10);
                var yenitarih = new Date();
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var checkoutStartDate = new Date(new Date(date).setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
                var checkoutEndDate = new Date(new Date(date).setDate(date.getDate() + 500000));
                $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", checkoutStartDate);
                $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker("option", "maxDate", checkoutEndDate);
            },
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
            }
        });
    $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: 'Temizle',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", false);
        },

        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find(".popover-wrapper").addClass("open");
        },
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");

        }

    });
    $(".main-checkin .input-form-inout").click(function() {
        $("#checkin").datepicker("show");
    });
    $(".main-checkout .input-form-inout").click(function() {
        $("#checkout").datepicker("show");
    });
}

datePicker();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" id="checkin">
<input type="text" id="checkout">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just checked on Safari 5+ for Windows. I can't even see the menu. Its not properly styled. Can you look into it. I think that might be associated with the issue.

Comment: you gotta check on mobile devices because this happens only on mobile devices

Comment: and thanks for checking

Comment: and another interesting issue I have Macintosh too and on Macintosh devices if I check it safari I can't see problem (as you live) but if I check on safari for windows yes I can't even see  the menu interesting